# Runtime errors with react using MUI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, styled-components

Below are the three source code files that are causing this error to happen, index.js , App.jss , Navbar.jss

```
index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


App.js
import Navbar from './Navbar.js';
function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
        </div> 
    );
}
export default App;

Navebar.js
import { AppBar, Toolbar , Grid } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <AppBar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Grid>

                    </Grid>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </>
    );
}
export default Navbar;
```

[runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9ov.png)

[no error in terminal after npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq4ZN.png)

Comment: You appear to be use using a [custom theme](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/) although there isn't one in the code in your post. You may need to wrap your app in a `<ThemeProvider>`.

Comment: Its not working even after i used the <ThemeProvider> to wrap the app, Its showing the same error

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your dependency bundle. Did you use `npm link` command? Check your dependencies in `package.json`. Maybe try deleting `node_modules` completely and reinstall everything.